# running eslint on project files

Tags: javascript, format, eslint

I'm trying to run **eslint** to fix code formation errors

1. I downloaded eslint locally on my project
2. I have eslintrc.js file that contain eslint configuration
3. when I run `npx eslint myfile.js` I  only get  this error `parse error unexpected token`

   dose this mean the format is ok and there is no issue with tapes space or anything related
   to code format, and if there is how to I run eslint to fix the errors


   ** ***my eslintrc file*** **

   ```js
       'use strict';

       module.exports = {
           "root": true,
           "parserOptions": {
               "ecmaVersion": 3,
               "sourceType": "script"
           },
           "env": {
               "node": true,
               "browser": true
           },
           "globals": {
               // Libraries
               "_": false, "$": false, "Backbone": false, "d3": false, "html": false, "html4": false, "jQuery": false, "SockJS": false, "ColorThief": false,

               // Environment-specific
               "fs": false, "gui": false, "ga": false, "macgap": false, "nwWindow": false, "webkitNotifications": false, "nw": false,

               // Battle stuff
               "Battle": true, "Pokemon": true, "BattleSound": true, "BattleTooltips": true, "BattleLog": true,
               "BattleAbilities": false, "BattleAliases": false, "BattleBackdrops": false, "BattleBackdropsFive": false, "BattleBackdropsFour": false, "BattleBackdropsThree": false, "BattleEffects": false,
               "BattleFormats": false, "BattleFormatsData": false, "BattleLearnsets": false, "BattleItems": false, "BattleMoveAnims": false, "BattleMovedex": false, "BattleNatures": false,
               "BattleOtherAnims": false,  "BattlePokedex": false,"BattlePokemonSprites": false, "BattlePokemonSpritesBW": false, "BattleSearchCountIndex": false, "BattleSearchIndex": false, "BattleArticleTitles": false,
               "BattleSearchIndexOffset": false, "BattleSearchIndexType": false, "BattleStatIDs": false, "BattleStatNames": false, "BattleStatusAnims": false, "BattleStatuses": false, "BattleTeambuilderTable": false,
               "ModifiableValue": false, "BattleStatGuesser": false, "BattleText": true, "BattleTextAFD": false, "BattleTextNotAFD": false,
               "BattleTextParser": false,

               // Generic global variables
               "Config": false, "BattleSearch": false, "Storage": false, "Dex": false, "DexSearch": false,
               "app": false, "toID": false, "toRoomid": false, "toUserid": false, "toName": false, "PSUtils": false, "MD5": false,
               "ChatHistory": false, "Topbar": false, "UserList": false,

               // Rooms
               "Room": false, "BattleRoom": false, "ChatRoom": false, "ConsoleRoom": false, "HTMLRoom": false, "LadderRoom": false, "MainMenuRoom": false, "RoomsRoom": false, "BattlesRoom": false, "TeambuilderRoom": false,

               // Tons of popups
               "Popup": false, "ForfeitPopup": false, "BracketPopup": false, "LoginPasswordPopup": false, "UserPopup": false, "UserOptionsPopup": false, "UserOptions": false, "TeamPopup": false,
               "AvatarsPopup": false, "CreditsPopup": false, "FormatPopup": false, "FormattingPopup": false, "LoginPopup": false,
               "MovePopup": false, "SoundsPopup": false, "OptionsPopup": false, "PromptPopup": false, "ProxyPopup": false, "ReconnectPopup": false,
               "RegisterPopup": false, "ReplayUploadedPopup": false, "RulesPopup": false, "TabListPopup": false, "TournamentBox": false,
               "CustomBackgroundPopup": false,

               // Test client
               "POKEMON_SHOWDOWN_TESTCLIENT_KEY": false
           },
           "extends": "eslint:recommended",
           "rules": {
               "no-cond-assign": ["error", "except-parens"],
               "no-console": "off",
               "no-constant-condition": "off",
               "no-control-regex": "off",
               "no-empty": ["error", {"allowEmptyCatch": true}],
               "no-inner-declarations": ["error", "functions"],
               "no-redeclare": "off",
               "valid-jsdoc": "off",

               // TODO: actually fix useless escapes
               "no-useless-escape": "off",

               "array-callback-return": "error",
               "complexity": "off",
               "consistent-return": "off",
               "default-case": "off",
               "dot-location": ["error", "property"],
               "dot-notation": "off",
               "eqeqeq": "off",
               "guard-for-in": "off",
               "no-caller": "error",
               "no-case-declarations": "off",
               "no-div-regex": "error",
               "no-else-return": "off",
               "no-labels": ["error", {"allowLoop": true, "allowSwitch": true}],
               "no-eval": "off",
               "no-implied-eval": "error",
               "no-extend-native": "error",
               "no-extra-bind": "warn",
               "no-extra-label": "error",
               "no-extra-parens": "off",
               "no-implicit-coercion": "off",
               "no-invalid-this": "off",
               "no-iterator": "error",
               "no-lone-blocks": "off",
               "no-loop-func": "off",
               "no-magic-numbers": "off",
               "no-multi-spaces": "warn",
               "no-multi-str": "error",
               "no-new-func": "error",
               "no-new-wrappers": "error",
               "no-octal-escape": "error",
               "no-param-reassign": "off",
               "no-proto": "error",
               "no-prototype-builtins": "error",
               "no-return-assign": ["error", "except-parens"],
               "no-self-compare": "error",
               "no-sequences": "error",
               "no-throw-literal": "error",
               "no-unmodified-loop-condition": "error",
               "no-unused-expressions": "error",
               "no-useless-call": "error",
               "no-useless-concat": "off",
               "no-void": "off",
               "no-warning-comments": "off",
               "no-with": "error",
               "radix": ["error", "always"],
               "vars-on-top": "off",
               "wrap-iife": ["error", "inside"],
               "yoda": "off",

               "init-declarations": "off",
               "no-catch-shadow": "off",
               "no-label-var": "error",
               "no-restricted-globals": ["error", "Proxy", "Reflect", "Symbol", "WeakSet"],
               "no-shadow-restricted-names": "error",
               "no-shadow": "off",
               "no-undef-init": "off",
               "no-undef": ["error", {"typeof": true}],
               "no-undefined": "off",
               "no-unused-vars": "off",

               "no-mixed-requires": "error",
               "no-new-require": "error",
               "no-path-concat": "off",
               "no-process-env": "off",
               "no-process-exit": "off",
               "no-restricted-modules": ["error", "moment", "request", "sugar"],
               "no-sync": "off",

               "array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "never"],
               "block-spacing": "off",
               "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs", {"allowSingleLine": true}],
               "camelcase": "off",
               "comma-spacing": ["error", {"before": false, "after": true}],
               "comma-style": ["error", "last"],
               "computed-property-spacing": ["error", "never"],
               "consistent-this": "off",
               "func-names": "off",
               "func-style": "off",
               "id-length": "off",
               "id-match": "off",
               "indent": ["error", "tab"],
               "key-spacing": "off",
               "lines-around-comment": "off",
               "max-nested-callbacks": "off",
               "max-statements-per-line": "off",
               "new-parens": "error",
               "newline-after-var": "off",
               "newline-before-return": "off",
               "no-array-constructor": "error",
               "no-continue": "off",
               "no-inline-comments": "off",
               "no-lonely-if": "off",
               "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": ["error", "smart-tabs"],
               "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", {"max": 2, "maxEOF": 1}],
               "no-negated-condition": "off",
               "no-nested-ternary": "off",
               "no-new-object": "error",
               "no-spaced-func": "error",
               "no-ternary": "off",
               "no-trailing-spaces": ["error", {"ignoreComments": false}],
               "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
               "no-unneeded-ternary": "error",
               "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"],
               "one-var": "off",
               "operator-assignment": "off",
               "operator-linebreak": ["error", "after"],
               "quote-props": "off",
               "quotes": "off",
               "require-jsdoc": "off",
               "semi-spacing": ["error", {"before": false, "after": true}],
               "semi": ["error", "always"],
               "sort-vars": "off",
               "keyword-spacing": ["error", {"before": true, "after": true}],
               "space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
               "space-before-function-paren": ["error", {"anonymous": "always", "named": "never"}],
               "space-in-parens": ["error", "never"],
               "space-infix-ops": "error",
               "space-unary-ops": ["error", {"words": true, "nonwords": false}],
               "wrap-regex": "off",

               "arrow-parens": ["error", "as-needed"],
               "arrow-spacing": ["error", {"before": true, "after": true}],
               "no-confusing-arrow": "off",
               "no-useless-computed-key": "error",
               "no-useless-rename": "error",
               "prefer-arrow-callback": "off",
               "rest-spread-spacing": ["error", "never"],
               "template-curly-spacing": ["error", "never"],
               "no-restricted-syntax": ["error", "TaggedTemplateExpression", "ObjectPattern", "ArrayPattern"],

               // Rules enabled in the server code, but disabled here
               /*
               "block-scoped-var": "error",
               "callback-return": [2, ["callback", "cb", "done"]],
               "comma-dangle": ["error", "always-multiline"],
               "curly": ["error", "multi-line", "consistent"],
               "eqeqeq": "error",
               "no-constant-condition": "error",
               "no-floating-decimal": "error",
               "no-new": "error",
               "no-redeclare": "error",
               "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {"args": "none"}],
               "no-use-before-define": ["error", {"functions": false, "classes": false}],
               "no-var": "error",
               "new-cap": ["error", {"newIsCap": true, "capIsNew: false}],
               "padded-blocks": ["error", "never"],
               "strict": ["error", "global"]
               */
           }
       };
   ```

***link to myfile.js***

https://gist.github.com/karamnaser/225e689d53a724009e8ebd3abf1d6371

Comment: Please share your eslintrc file

Comment: Do you get any line or file where this error happens? We can't know it it's eslint file parse error or your file. Btw, `myfile.js` is the longest js file I have seen in my life

Comment: full message is **130:10 error parsin error : unexpected token config** , config is an js object  in function called creatFormobserver() and ther is no issue with that object , the file is part of open source game im trying to work on